# How to create autofit view android

Tags: android, orientation

In android Can I able to create a view like this using Linear layout?

[image]

Comment: using Linear layout?  NO . Its possible with `FlexBoxLayout` . What going on with the last textView ?  Its text arrangement is weird,  if its same as the first 4 `TextView`  Try using `FlexBoxLayout`. The way your last `TextView` is showing right now in picture its not possible you might have to create a Custom view for it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create view using FlexBoxLayout, Here is the solution,

Add the following dependency to your build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:1.1.0'
}
```

Adding the FlexBoxLayout to the layout,

```
           <com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                app:flexDirection="row"
                app:flexWrap="wrap"
                app:justifyContent="flex_start">


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    android:text="Sample Text 1" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    android:text="Sample Text 2"  />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    android:text="Sample Text 3" />

            </com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>
```